# "administration to rhesus macaques" vs. "administration in rhesus macaques"

Tags: prepositions

> This study compares the immunotoxic effects of repeated administration of two monoclonal antibodies, ABC-12 (RusBio, lot #1023) and Herceptin (Hoffmann-La Roche, Switzerland), **to** rhesus macaques (Macaca mulatta).

Can one use the preposition "in" there? I googled around, and found that drugs are administered "to" patients, but would "in" be passable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Passable"? Yes, because it is understandable.

I know we say *administer to*, and I did some ngram searches on it. *Administer to* and *administer in* seemed very close. So I added some context regarding patients, and it seems that *to* is preferable.
[image]
***Administer to patients vs. administer in patients***

[image]
**Administer to/in patients, administered to/in patients, administration to/in patients**

Then I expanded my search and it looks like *administration to/in* is special.
[image]
In the following search, Google provided some preceding words for context.
[image]

So I think *in* is still wrong, since you administer stuff (for example, drugs) *to* someone, but *in* seems to have gained popularity in recent years.

However, I would still prefer *to*.